Grapes of Wrath Passage Confusion
I have a question (which I previously asked in the English community rather than this one) about a couple of sentences from this passage in Grapes of Wrath, after Tom and Al are driving to a town as they make their way to California:

"Well, look, Tom. I got six dollars. You an' me could get a couple pints an' go down the line. Nobody don't know I got that six bucks. Christ, we could have a hell of a time for ourselves."
"Keep ya jack," Tom said. "When we get out to the coast you an' me'll take her an' we'll raise hell. Maybe when we're workin'—" He turned in the seat. "I didn' think you was a fella to go down the line. I figgered you was talkin' 'em out of it."
"Well, hell, I don't know nobody here. If I'm gonna ride aroun' much, I'm gonna get married. I'm gonna have me a hell of a time when we get to California."

Basically I'm confused about what Al means when he says "If I'm gonna ride aroun' much, I'm gonna get married." Is this said sarcastically considering he's just suggested that he and Tom go to prostitutes ("go down the line")? If not, what could this mean? I thought "riding around" literally meant driving, but does he mean something sexual?
